# Ubuntu 20.04: Why does available disk space amount vary depending on what program I am using to view it?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, ram, disk-usage, disk-management

I have a 480GB Kingston SSD, and of that, 471GB is what's fully available to me. This is okay. The issue comes after installation of my OS, and various other software like IDEs, VMware, etc.

When I check to see how much space I have available, I get different answers depending on if I am using the Disk Usage Analyzer, or when looking at the Properties for the drive (or file system in the System Monitor). Here are screenshots to show what I mean. I am wondering why this is the case.

[Disk Usage Analyser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rCSx.png);
[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI6pU.png);
[System Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnZOr.png)

I hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Disk Analyzer treats reserved space as available, while others treat it as unavailable. 5% of any ext4 filesystem space is reserved by default, which, in your case amounts to 471*0.05=23.55GB.

I hope my answer is clear. :~)

Comment: Hey, I had to look into why ext4 did that, and I found out it reserved memory blocks to allow root access and services to properly function, as well as to better deal with fragmentation. Thank you! Your answer help a lot :D